# Disable wordpress plugin updates during business hours

Tags: wordpress

I've attempted some other solutions to disable plugin updates during set hours without luck. Plugin updates are running at midnight and noon. The noon updates are causing a down for maintenance page that I need to avoid, as well as the email sent to me notifying me of the recent updates.

The following code is in wp-config.php

```
$current_time = current_datetime()->format( 'Hi' );
$business_hours = ( $current_time > 700 && $current_time < 2200 );
if($business_hours){
    define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
    define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
    add_filter('auto_update_plugin', '__return_false');
}
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Further, when I try to output the constants `AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED` and WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE from my functions.php it throws the "Undefined constant" error. I've searched the entire codebase for the constants being unset but I couldn't find it. I've tried several variations:

```
error_log(AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED);
error_log('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED');
error_log(constant(AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED));
error_log(constant('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED'));
```

The last bit of info I have is that Wordfence diagnostics does tell me the updates are disabled if I check during business hours.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: This function would make a useful plugin. But it sure would be a pain in the xxs neck to debug.

Comment: Maybe help you these [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190616/schedule-wordpress-auto-updates-to-only-run-during-business-hours) or [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157577/alter-how-often-wordpress-auto-updates-plugins)

Comment: Those two links are where I got the code I'm using. But I appreciate you looking.